# Como hacer transiciones suavizadas con vue js

Tags: vue.js, transacciones, animated

Intento hacer transiciones entre componentes en vue js
lo que intento es hacer un tipo de slider con un formulario, cada cara es un componente y al presionar continuar cambia el componente hacia la derecha y si presionan retroceder va hacia la izquierda.

son los estilos que ocupo

```
    .fadeInLeft-enter-active {
        animation: slideInRight 1s;
    }
    .fadeInLeft-leave-active {
        animation: slideInLeft .5s reverse;
    }
    .fadeInRight-enter-active {
        animation: slideInLeft 1s;
    }
    .fadeInRight-enter-active {

        animation: slideInRight .5s reverse;
    }
```

si voy hacia delante las animaciones se ven bien pero si presiono regresa la animación la hace mal.

Comment: Como tenes definidas las transiciones en tu template. probaste con animate.css que ya tiene todas las transiciones escritas?

Comment: Si te das cuenta estoy ocupando animate, con la variable animation que esta bindiada de esta forma :name="animation" cambio la animación según sea el caso

Comment: Ok podras entonces compartir un [mcve] de tu template

Answer (score 1):

Usando estas clases puedes hacer que un elemento aparezca con un fade y trasladándose hacia la izquierda, con el cambio de la variable "showItem" que tengas en tu "data".

```
.fadeInLeft-enter-active {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.fadeInLeft-leave-active {
  transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}
.fadeInLeft-enter, . fadeInLeft-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(-100px);
  opacity: 0;
}



<transition name="slide-up" mode="in-out">
  <div v-if="showItem"></div>
</transition>
```